# A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'Request'

Tags: c#, datatable, datasource, reportviewer, rdlc

I'm getting an error on my reportviewer which I am not sure how to correct this.... 
The error that I am gettings is : " A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'Request'."
I have tried searching for this, but can't find anything that I can see that is wrong, can somebody please point me in the right direction? This is how my reportvierer looks like:

```
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Height="654px" 
Width="924px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" 
    InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
    WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Report.rdlc">
    </LocalReport>
```

This is the code I use for the reportviewer:

```
    SqlConnection conn;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    conn.Open();

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        runRptViewer();
    } 

}
    private DataTable getData()
{
    DataSet dss = new DataSet();
    string sql = "";
    sql = "SELECT CC_Request.Company, CC_Request.Attention, CC_Request.Telephone, CC_Request.Email, CC_Items.Model, CC_Items.SerialNo, CC_ItemsRequested.Item, CC_ItemsRequested.Quantity, CC_ItemsRequested.Price, CC_ItemsRequested.ModelID, CC_Items.RequestID FROM CC_Request INNER JOIN CC_Items ON CC_Request.RequestID = CC_Items.RequestID INNER JOIN CC_ItemsRequested ON CC_Items.ModelID = CC_ItemsRequested.ModelID WHERE (CC_Request.Company = 'Alpha') AND (CC_ItemsRequested.ModelID = 20) AND (CC_Items.RequestID = 1)";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    da.Fill(dss);
    DataTable dt = dss.Tables[0];
    return dt;
}

private void runRptViewer()
{
    this.rptViewer.Reset();
    this.rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Reports\\Report.rdlc");
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsNewDataSet_Table", getData());
    this.rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    this.rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    this.rptViewer.DataBind();
    this.rptViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT-----------------------

this does not work either:

```
    private DataTable getData()
{
    DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
    dtable.TableName = "dtNewDataSet_Table";
    string sql = "";
    sql = "SELECT CC_Request.Company, CC_Request.Attention, CC_Request.Telephone, CC_Request.Email, CC_Items.Model, CC_Items.SerialNo, CC_ItemsRequested.Item, CC_ItemsRequested.Quantity, CC_ItemsRequested.Price, CC_ItemsRequested.ModelID, CC_Items.RequestID FROM CC_Request INNER JOIN CC_Items ON CC_Request.RequestID = CC_Items.RequestID INNER JOIN CC_ItemsRequested ON CC_Items.ModelID = CC_ItemsRequested.ModelID WHERE (CC_Request.Company = 'Alpha') AND (CC_ItemsRequested.ModelID = 20) AND (CC_Items.RequestID = 1)";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    da.Fill(dtable);
    DataTable dt = dtable;
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Side-note: why do you create and fill a `DataSet` when you only return it's first table anyway? Create a `DataTable` and fill that.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, that doesn't work either.....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was also facing this problem that's why I came here.

I figure out the problem and I am posting that here to help some one who get this type of issue.

1. My data source of RDLC was **"dsClientPayList"**
2. I was adding the data source in my code behind like:

   ```
   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); 
   ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("dsData1", DAL.MyDBModel.snData().Tables[0]);
   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd);
   ```

and it was throwing same error.

Solution:

In my code behind I changed the parameter of ReportDataSource from "**dsData1**" to "**dsClientPayList**" (same as in RDLC).

```
ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("dsClientPayList", DAL.MyDBModel.snData().Tables[0]);
```

And it works

Conclusion: ***The DataSource name must be same in both RDLC and ReportViewer.***

Thanks
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set all of the datasources that using in the report.

In this case if there is only one datasource it should be like this

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("Request", getData());
```

Comment: it there is multiple (I've got 3) do I must add 3 ReportDataSources and then add them 3 times to the Local Report Data Sources? I have done this, but it casuses the reportviewer to go not display (like being totally invisible)?

Comment: yes, add all of those datasources being used in your report, ensure the datasource name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it with "using" statement for correct object disposal and error handling

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand()) {
comm.Connection = conn;
comm.CommandText = sql;
```

...

```
try {
conn.Open();
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(SqlException e) {
// in case something is wrong
}
}
}
```