# A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet2'-SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

This is my First report using SSRS.

I am trying to generate a Report using SSRS in asp.net.

My Need is:

I want to create a report with multiple tables (4 tables) that have relationship with one another. I have configured each individual table with accepting 1 parameter, for instance:
  [image]

What I tried is:

I have created a dataset.xsd with 4 tables and given the relationship between those tables.
Then I created a report.rdlc and designed a report with four tables and drag and dropped the required field to the table and created a report parameter called ID.

The error i'm Getting is:

`A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet2'`

[image]

What I have written in cs page on button click is:

```
protected void BtnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet2TableAdapters.TB_TransReceiptTableAdapter ta = new DataSet2TableAdapters.TB_TransReceiptTableAdapter();
            DataSet2.TB_TransReceiptDataTable dt = new DataSet2.TB_TransReceiptDataTable();
            ta.Fill(dt,Convert.ToInt16( TxtID.Text));
            //ta.Fill(dt,TxtID.Text);
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
            rds.Name = "DataSet2";
            rds.Value = dt;
            ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("ID", TxtID.Text.ToString());
            rptviewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            rptviewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
            rptviewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
            rptviewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            rptviewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
            rptviewer.Visible = true;
        }
```

The help i seek is:

I dont know how to bind the report via code, since I have four tables that are related to one another with foreign key. Above is the code I used but it throws an error.

I would be very thankful if some one could help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781133/a-data-source-instance-has-not-been-supplied-for-the-data-source-request?rq=1

Comment: No there is no duplicate since in dataset while configuring i have used the query as<< SELECT   Distinct   tREC_NUPKId, tREC_NUIsActive, tREC_mCMP_NUUniqueId, tREC_VCVoucherNo, tREC_DTEVoucherDate, tREC_mVTP_NUPKId
FROM            TB_TransReceipt
WHERE        (tREC_NUPKId = @ID)>>

Comment: Also, it sounds like your report is using four tables and you have only loaded one and bound the table instead of the dataset (containing all four tables).  Am I seeing that right?

Comment: YUP!!! ...But Really i dont know how to bound the four tables at a time :(

Comment: I think you are missing the point of S/O.  Of course every report will use a different query.  However, the programming concepts will be very similar.  Namely, in the duplicate solution, the answer points-out that your data table needs to have the same name in your dataset and in your report.  I'm pretty sure that is your solution.

Comment: Otherwise, the line datasources.add(), can be called multiple times.  Once for each table.  It is a lot of code.

Comment: Hope Your Suggestion help me to come out from this rid let me give a try.

Comment: Hi thanks Mr. tgolisch Really your suggestion helped me alot to solve my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per  tgolisch  instead of table i Bound dataset and passed to report it works fine.
And also instead of four separate table i created a view .It Makes my job simple

```
 private DataTable getData()
        {
            DataSet dss = new DataSet();
            string sql = "";
            sql = "SELECT * from VW_TransReciptReport WHERE tREC_NUPKId='" + TxtID.Text + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            da.Fill(dss);
            DataTable dt = dss.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }

        private void runRptViewer()
        {
            this.rptviewer.Reset();
            ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("ID", TxtID.Text.ToString());
            this.rptviewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("ReportReceipt.rdlc");
            rptviewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
            ReportDataSource rdsB = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1_VW_TransReciptReport", getData());

            this.rptviewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.rptviewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsB);

            this.rptviewer.DataBind();
            this.rptviewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
```